# CODEXSHAPER - LARAVEL - cURL Error: HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: Unknown error code (err 1)

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress, curl

I am making a PUT of an item through CODEXSHAPER but I am receiving this return:

> cURL Error: HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: Unknown error code (err 1)

From what I checked CURL is encapsulated in the framework, how do I make this change?

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
```

Comment: It's hard to say anything without seeing the full code. Also note that Laravel has a built-in [HTTP client](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client) which provides a much higher-level API than using curl directly.

Comment: but in this case would the GUZZLE be correct? And it would not return this CURL error